# can not access webpage django

Tags: python, django

i am working on user's page on django. i want to enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/2 and get my template but django says `The current path, user/2, didn’t match any of these.`

my view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import *

def UserPage(request,user_num):
    #get user info
    username = "none"
    posts = []#post("test", "none")
    status = 'aboba'
    return render(
        request,
        'userpage.html',
        context={'username': username, 'posts': posts, 'status': status},
    )
```

my urls:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^user/(?P<user_num>\d+)$', views.UserPage, name='userpage'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because you're mixing a [regex path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re-path) and a regular [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#path), either get rid of the regex stuff or use a `re_path`

```
 path('user/<user_num>'
```

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'^user/(?P<user_num>\d+)$'
```